# How to change the name of the second player in Rocket League?

Tags: pc, rocket-league

The player name in Rocket League is the Steam name by default. When playing in split-screen mode, the second player's name is `Steam Name(2)`.

I have tried a few things suggested in [Youtube Videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGXlAADHXnY):

- modify the Registry (the mentioned key does not exist in my Registry)
- change `ALI231.ini` (doesn't exist on my PC)
- change `Steam_API.ini` (doesn't exist on my PC)

Comment: Worth noting this behavior is replicated when playing as a Guest on the Xbox One version as well.

Comment: Have you tried just creating the missing key / file and writing what is suggested in the videos into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I have seen, this is an intended feature and cannot be fixed for local split-screen players.

From [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/252950/discussions/0/492379439687599337/):

> They are all playing on your account, that's why it does that.

On PS4, it does this as well if the other players are logged in as guests, but displays their usernames if they log in.